# the maximum amount of characters in a domain name

Tags: url, dns, uri

What the maximum amount of characters a domain name can be? What about a Url? Is there any differences between `ASCII` and `non-ASCII` characters? So thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fully qualified domain name like `www.example.com`:

- each parts between dots, named labels, must be less than 63 octets
- the whole FQDN, including dots, must be less than 255 octets

Those limits are described in the [RFC 1035 section 2.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-2.3.4)

For an full `ASCII` domain name, this means an 1 octet = 1 character.

Concerning the `non-ASCII` domain there is a notation named [International Domain Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (IDN) which uses Punycode to convert the Unicode to ASCII, and prefixed by the ASCII Compatible Encoding `xn--` (ACE) to differentiate it with standard labels. It is the resulting string that is being used for comparison with the limits.

**example:**

The IDN `www.école.com` is converted to `www.xn--cole-9oa.com` (20 characters)

Concerning the URL limits, please refer to the popular thread on stackoverflow "[What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)"